# Google Cloud Products Virtual Machine .NET Needs Memory Limits Update

Tags: .net, memory-management, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am receiving a 502 error and don't know how to increase my memory limit. It is a .NET application being hosted in my GCP Compute Engine Virtual Machine instance.

It is not a matter of increasing the CPU size of the Virtual Machine instance.

GCP stops my file upload and processing program on said file when it goes beyond a memory limit and I get a 502 error.

In Python applications, Google documentation says to configure memory limits in an app.yaml file. There is no answer for a .NET application in a Windows license Virtual Machine instance.

This resource suggested updating the Compute Engine limits with the Google console: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits

This command brings up some other questions: `gcloud run services update SERVICE --memory SIZE`. What can I replace 'update' with to find out my current memory size? What do I update it to and what is the cost?

Overall, to prevent the 502 error on memory processing used for file upload:

1. Do I adjust the memory limit of the service Cloud Engine, or the Virtual Machine instance, or the Project, or something else?
2. What is the change in price for doing this, since memory usage is not on the billing report?
3. How do I change the memory limits being enforced on file upload specifically for a .NET Windows VM application?
4. In the browser inspection section Memory in Google Chrome, keeping the page on the 502 error, there was some use of memory being reported as 'Select JavaScript VM instance' that changed without webpage interaction- what is this?

I know it is a memory limit, because the same application with the same configurations is working when hosted on the internal IP address inside the VM, but it is not working when hosted by the VM's external IP address by GCP, so it is a matter of adjusting a memory setting in GCP somewhere.

Comment: You left out two important details. What is the instance size (memory) and what is the file size? You do not show the code nor the library that you are using to handle file uploads. Some libraries upload into memory, which means you need more memory than the maximum file size. The quick fix to to increase the VM memory size (instance size). The best solution is learn how your library works and write code that handles your requirements.

Comment: I have already increased my VM instance well beyond what the file size being uploaded is. It now stands around 8gB and the file being uploaded is roughly 10mB. According to documentation, it is a separate memory limit enforced by GCP which can be adjusted. In Python it is set in app.yaml. In .NET Windows VM there is no answer in docs. I think it's relevant to how much memory is allowed to stream in a Compute Engine hosting an instance, but there is no explicit reference.

Comment: Also, it is likely not a library problem, because it works fine in the internal IP and also on localhost. The only time it doesn't upload is when it is run through the GCP host as an external IP address for the VM.

Comment: GCP does not define a memory limit (variable/setting) that affects your library. If the file size is 10 MB, you have a bug in your code. You have not posted your code.

Comment: It can't be a bug, because the code works fine in localhost and internal IP. I'm not using a library to upload my files.

Comment: I voted to close your question. Your question needs focus and lacks clear/specific details. You need to show your code, errors that occur, and a clear explanation of a single issue. Read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example